# EF Core 6 & C# : converting from string to datetime not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, ef-core-6.0

I tried to convert an entered string date `'12/23/2023'` to a `datetime`, but it's not working.

I tried it using:

Code snippet #1:

```
DateTime? dtmDate = null;
value = "12/23/2023";
string[] dateString = value.Split('/');
dtmDate =  Convert.ToDateTime(dateString[0] + "/" + dateString[1] + "/" + dateString[2]); 

// Expected output : string "12/28/2023" to datetime: 12/18/2023
```

Code snippet #2:

```
var string = "12/28/2023"
dtmDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(string, "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is also not working.. the format of my SQL is:

```
2023-12-23 00:00:00.000
```

Please help me out

I get this error:

> System.FormatException: String '12/23/2023' was not recognized as a
> valid DateTime.
>
> at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)

Comment: Check your input & expected result, it doesn't make sense that the date string: 12/28/2023 will convert to 12/18/2023, same goes to 2023-12-23. And provide the error info that when you use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for time, I edited my question, it should be "12/23/2023" what I want is to convert it to datetime, I matches the format which is "MM/dd/yyyy" but does not work for me please help me

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: so.. which part in this question related to [tag:ef-core-6.0]? are you trying to insert stuff in SQL using raw query or something? also, depending on your RDBMS they might have [`Date` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) without time of day.

Comment: Hi sir , currently im using Web api in Asp.net Core and relying on EF 6. and trying to convert string date to datetime

Comment: @Bryanart well, `DateTime` in the database will always have the `Time` part regardless of how you format the data in your app. c#'s `DateTime` always have the `Time` part too, use [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-8.0) if you dislike the `Time` part. but remember its for ef 8, [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#sqlserver-date-time-only).

Comment: Can I have your more ensight sir on how we include taht in my project please

Comment: @Bryanart thats quite the task.. to be honest it would be far easier to detach your idea of representation and storage must have the same "format." let the DB do its thing, just format the date properly when you print them for end users.

Comment: What is the datatype of that date column in your database? If it is some 'date' type, then you shouldn't convert it to string and parse yourself, but put it in the correct c# type

Comment: Your question is a bit confused. I assume your "sql format" is the value stored in the database - this does not match your snippets. And your error (about Parse) does not match them either

Comment: @HansKeﬆing its Datetime datatype, when I add data on that column it should be "2023-12-23 00:00:00.000" then my problem is I tried to retrieve the data base on the inputted string date example "12/23/2023"  then convert it to datetime so that we can send a paramater dtmDate into Stored Procedure and to Get the data where the date is 12/23/2023

Comment: A variable of type DateTime *does not have a format*, that's just the debugger showing a printable value. So probably you do not have to do *anything*

Comment: So in your Stored procedure, you need to have a filter criteria that the search date must be fall under specified date with:  `WHERE <Date column> >= @DtmDate AND <Date column> < DATEADD(day,1, @DtmDate)`

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want to do it @YongShun

Comment: What does EF Core have to do with this? What does SQL have to do with this, where is the rest of the SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-8.0) method when you have a specific date string format to convert into `DateTime`.

While the method returns a boolean value indicates the date string can be converted into DateTime. To get the `DateTime` value, you need to get it from the `out` parameter.

Also, you will get the compilation error from `string` as it is a type ([reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)). You should either rename or use the `@` prefix.

```cs
var @string = "12/28/2023";

bool isDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(@string, 
    "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out DateTime dtmDate);
```

Comment: Hi sir I tried it but it returns dtmDate = {23/12/2023 12:00:00 am} as output. and get the same error :(

Comment: What error did you get? [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xf7nF0)

Comment: I get these : System.FormatException: String '12/23/2023' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)

Comment: @Bryanart its `DateTime.TryParseExact` not `DateTime.Parse`.

Comment: Hi sir @BagusTesa , I already use DateTime.TryParseExact but it seems getting the same error

Comment: @Bryanart uh, `DateTime.TryParseExact` wont throw an exception, it will silently return `false` and the `dtmDate` set to default. i'm not sure if you run the right code, did you rebuild your project? try the link provided by Yong Shun, put random non-date string on `@string` and see it wont throw any error.

Comment: bool isDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(@string,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None,
                    out DateTime dtmDate);  this is the code I used

Comment: When I try to hover the output it will do 23/12/2023 12:00:00 am not 12/23/2023

Comment: @Bryanart because its `DateTime`.. it always **have** the `Time` component.

Comment: please help me sir @BagusTesa how to do it. it seems getting error continuously, my inputted string is "12/23/2023"

Comment: @Bryanart `DateOnly.FromDateTime(dtmDate)`, this will give you the `DateOnly`, [see demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gaIiDm). but i have no clue if you can put it in the DB, we have no knowledge of your model and migration.

Comment: I already have a date on my SQL it will do "2023-12-23 00:00:00.000"  its an existing data on my database , what I do is trying to get the data base on the date example "12/23/2023" as inputted data

Comment: *"trying to get the data base on the date example "12/23/2023" as inputted data"* - the `DateTime` in database has no format per se as Zohar explained. if you wanted it to have only `Date` use the appropriate data type, but how it represented to a human left to the DBMS client. **formatting the representation on end user is what your app should do**.